# Kotlin - Reading a video from a path to process it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

So I have a button in my layout and upon clicking it, I want to send a videofile path to the function which processes the frames of the video to return the heart rate.

Here is my code where I am trying to generate the video path:

```
val videoFileName = "heartrate_video.mp4"
        val videoFile = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Android/data/com.guardianangel.myguardian/files/Movies/$videoFileName")

if (videoFile != null) {
            // Execute the AsyncTask to calculate heart rate
            val slowTask = SlowTask { heartRate ->
                // Display the heart rate as a toast message
                showToast("Heart Rate: $heartRate bpm")
                Log.d("Heart Rate", "Heart rate: $heartRate")
            }
            slowTask.execute(videoFile.absolutePath)
        } else {
            // Handle the case where the video file does not exist
            Log.e("VideoPath", "Video file does not exist")
        }
```

Despite having the video file in the location, it always goes to the else condition and prints Video file does not exist.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems okay. Make sure you have these read and write permissions in your manifest file and ask for them at runtime.

(Or just accept them from settings -> permissions for testing purposes.)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I did add these permissions in the xml file. Can you tell me how to request them while runtime?